# Radiance Calculation of Landsat 7 with Google Earth Engine(search for gain and bias)

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, metadata, landsat-7

I need to calculate the Radiance of Landsat 7 in GEE
I read in [Data Users Handbook](https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-7-data-users-handbook-section-5) under 5.6.5 how to do this. Here it says, these Values are accessible in the Metadata. Now I am searching the Metadata for Gain and Bias in GEE
[Link to GEECode](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2d12a75699bd1bca0a027782f414c861).
I made a list of all Property names and can not find it.
Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging your input, you can't. You are using a corrected product:

[image]

To calculate radiance of a Landsat Image use an uncorrected product, i.e. **USGS Landsat 7 Collection 1 Tier 1 and Real-Time data Raw Scenes**. This kind of product has gain and bias.

So change:

```
LSatTMC = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR")
```

for

```
LSatTMC = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_RT")
```

And check metadata information